# ASP.Net - Esc Key Stops My 'Send Email' Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a webform which on one page has a submit button. This submit button displays a processing modal whilst the email is tried to be sent. If the email sends, the page redirects, if it fails an error message is displayed.  All this works fine but I have found an issue where if the user was the hit the 'Esc' key, no email is sent and it doesn't fall into my `catch`.  It appears to stop my email process completely.

How can I ensure that if the user clicks the Esc key (or possibly and other key) that the process still carries on.  Bit of a stage one I know.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="pg3button" runat="server" OnClick="pg3button_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClientclick="ShowPopup();"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Send & complete</asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModalTitle" runat="server" Text="">Processing</asp:Label>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblModalBody" runat="server" Text="">
                        <p class="text-center">
                            <img src="../Content/Images/loading.gif" />
                        </p>
                    </asp:Label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function ShowPopup()
        {
           $('#myModal').modal();
        }
    </script>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void pg3button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    try
    {
        //Create the msg object to be sent
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        //Add your email address to the recipients
        msg.To.Add("test@test.co.uk");

        //Configure the address we are sending the mail from
        MailAddress address = new MailAddress("test@test.co.uk");
        msg.From = address;

        //Append their name in the beginning of the subject
        msg.Subject = "Enquiry";

        msg.Body = Label1.Text + " " + Session["pg1input"].ToString()
                    + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
                    Label2.Text + " " + Session["pg1dd"].ToString()
                    + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
                    Label3.Text + " " + Session["pg2"].ToString();

        //Configure an SmtpClient to send the mail.
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
        client.EnableSsl = true; //only enable this if your provider requires it

        //Setup credentials to login to our sender email address ("UserName", "Password")
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("test@test.co.uk", "Password10");
        client.Credentials = credentials;

        //Send the msg
        client.Send(msg);

        Response.Redirect("/Session/pg4.aspx");
    }
    catch
    {
        //If the message failed at some point, let the user know
        lblResult.Text = "<div class=\"form-group\">" + "<div class=\"col-xs-12\">" + "There was a problem sending your request. Please try again." + "</div>" + "</div>" + "<div class=\"form-group\">" + "<div class=\"col-xs-12\">" + "If the error persists, please contact us." + "</div>" + "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't, you are essentially asking "how can I stop the user cancelling a partially submitted form".

Comment: @BenRobinson unless I am misunderstanding the problem, whats stopping him from just handling the key press event and canceling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix that I found that worked for me was adding the below to the top of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event)
    {
        // if the keyCode is 27 ( Esc )
        if (event.keyCode === 27)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        // if the keyCode is 116 ( F5 )
        if (event.keyCode === 116) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

        // if the keyCode is 8 ( Backspace )
        if (event.keyCode === 8) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use some javascript IMO, something like this at the top of your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
    switch (e.keyCode) {

    case 116 : // 'F5'
         event.returnValue = false;
         event.keyCode = 0;
         break;  

    case 27: // 'Esc'
        event.returnValue = false;
        event.keyCode = 0;
        break;

    }
}
</script>
```

this is an example of how you can check for multiple key codes. you can use this same logic to check for any kind of key presses and handle them however you see fit.

[Here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) is a list of keycodes incase you need them

Comment: unfortunetly you solution didn't wort but when looking at your I managed to fix it myself. Thanks for the help though and giving me the starting blocks